Could not find us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2
In my Kotlin Project, when I try to generate (build) the APK, I get this error:

Could not find us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2.

I tried to manually download the module and import, yet im running into errors -
:app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug
Could not resolve us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2
Could not find us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2.
If there is anybody who knows how to solve this, I would really appreciate some help at the moment.
Here is my build.gradle.
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    def value = 1
    Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    if (!versionPropsFile.exists()) {
        versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'] = "1"
        versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'] = "-1"
        versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = "-1" // I set it to minus one so the first build is 0 which isn't super important.
        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
    }

    def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
    if ('assembleRelease' in runTasks) {
        value = 1
    }

    def mVersionName = ""
    def mFileName = ""

    if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))

        versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'] = (versionProps['VERSION_PATCH'].toInteger() + value).toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'] = (versionProps['VERSION_NUMBER'].toInteger() + value).toString()
        versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = (versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + value).toString()

        versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

        // 1: change major and minor version here
        mVersionName = "1.5.${versionProps['VERSION_PATCH']}"
        // 2: change AppName for your app name
        mFileName = "AppName-${mVersionName}.apk"

        defaultConfig {
//  versionName "${mVersionName} Build: ${versionProps['VERSION_BUILD']}"
        applicationId "com.example.esales"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "${mVersionName}"
        resConfigs "en"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    }else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not read version.properties!")
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField("int", "BUILD_TIME", System.currentTimeSeconds().toString())
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_DATE", "\"${new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date())}\""
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_DATE", "\"${new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date())}\""
            useProguard true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/NOTICE.md")
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/LICENSE.md")
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/DEPENDENCIES")
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioRecognizer.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_imgproc.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_imgproc.so'
        exclude 'lib/mips/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioRecognizer.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libopencv_core.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libopencv_imgproc.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioRecognizer.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libopencv_core.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libopencv_imgproc.so'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    def appCenterSdkVersion = '4.3.1'
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
    implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"

    // Okhttp3 for the POST requests
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'

    // Gson (To convert raw JSON to pretty JSON)
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    //Navigation Drawer
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha01'

    //recyclerView
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'

    //bt printer
    implementation 'com.github.dantsu:escpos-thermalprinter-android:2.0.11'
    
    //circle Image
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    // Coroutines to make the HTTP requests asynchronous(In the background thread)

    implementation ('org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.3-native-mt')
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"

    //MPChart
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

//    // iText PDF
//    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'

    //pdfViewer
    implementation('com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.3')
    //progressDialog
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"

    //bottomNavigatorNew
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    //picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    //toggleswitchupdated
    implementation("us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2")
    //quickaction
    implementation 'com.github.piruin:quickaction:2.4.3'

    //searchinvoice
    implementation 'com.github.miteshpithadiya:SearchableSpinner:master'

    //BarcodeScanner
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'



    //SwipeRecycerView
    implementation 'com.github.tsuryo:Swipeable-RecyclerView:1.1'

    //floating button
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'

    //image Badge View
    implementation("com.github.nikartm:image-support:1.1.0")

    //implementation 'nl.bryanderidder:themed-toggle-button-group:1.4.1' //this not used remove if need

    implementation 'com.github.psinetron:slycalendarview:0.0.9'

    //longlatgoogle
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'

    //gmail server
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.6'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.7'

    //signature openCv

    implementation 'com.github.nsmarinro.SignatureView:librarySignature:0.1.2'


//Drive
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.1')

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'

    implementation 'com.github.ligi:tracedroid:4.1'

    //btprint
    implementation 'com.github.anggastudio:Printama:0.9.7'

    //new spinner 
    implementation 'com.github.arcadefire:nice-spinner:1.4.4'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0'

}


Can you provide your build.gradle?

Maybe you didn't add this line to build.gradle:
    implementation("us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2")

BTW, Based on the Github repository readme of the library:

Deprecation notice: this library is no longer maintained. If you are currently using it, we reccomend switching to the fork by its original developer: https://github.com/llollox/Android-Toggle-Switch


I do have added the line,
implementation("us.belka:androidtoggleswitch:1.2.2")


Another reason can be the depreciation of dependency, I suggest you install the suggested version based on the publisher's note.
